# Error running MVC spring application nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am not using Maven for my web application. I have posted the following screenshot of the jars which I have included in the classpath.

[image: Jars included in the classpath]

When running the application I am getting the following error -

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet employee threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cybage.projects.service.EmployeeService com.cybage.projects.controller.EmployeeController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cybage.projects.dao.EmployeeDao com.cybage.projects.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EmployeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.cybage.projects.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect  
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cybage.projects.service.EmployeeService com.cybage.projects.controller.EmployeeController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cybage.projects.dao.EmployeeDao com.cybage.projects.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EmployeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.cybage.projects.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect  
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.
```

`Employee-servlet.xml` has following entry of the bean-

[image: Entry in the Employee-servlet.xml]

Following is the screen shot of the `database.properties`

[image]

I checked that MySQL5Dialect class is present in the jar hibernate-3.2.4.ga.jar but not sure why its still throwing error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For starters fix your jars (and I would really suggest to use maven). You are mixing 3 spring versions. (2.0, 3.0.1 and 3.2) don't do that. Also instead of screenshots, please post actual code and format it correctly. Thatis far more readable then screenshots...

Comment: Can you just pin point which combinations of jars I should be using?

Comment: The above issue just called solved. When ever you are giving key value pairs in database.properties, make sure there is no space left after value before saving. I removed the unnecessary space and the issue got resolved.